# AppArmor automatic profiles

Tags: apparmor

I tried using aa-genprof to create a profile of the Splunk daemon.  I started, stopped, and restarted Splunk.  I downloaded and installed apps from the Splunkbase.  I enabled inputs that open network ports and run python scripts.

After performing all of those different actions, when I look at the profile that aa-genprof generated, it looks like this:

```
include <tunables/global>

/opt/splunk/bin/splunkd flags=(complain) {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-*.so mr,
  /opt/splunk/bin/splunkd mr,

}
```

No capabilities defined.  No read permissions created for config files.  I don't see any of the content I see in profiles I find on the Internet.

I'm using the CIS benchmark audit.rules file, so the audit daemon is auditing behavior pretty aggressively.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is this expected behavior and most of the profiles need to be written by hand?

Thx.

Comment: Does this profile allow your app to do its job?

Comment: It does, but I haven't yet tested whether or not it blocks my app from doing things it shouldn't...

Comment: Please test it as this might be all you need to run the app!